# How to share an image from the Internet without saving it?

Tags: android, android-intent, share

I'm trying to share an image from the internet using share intents. This doesn't work because I think the image needs to be downloaded first:

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
```

So I'm downloading an image and then sharing it:

```
@Background
protected void tryToShareImage(Intent intent) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(mImageUrl);
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, getImageUri(mActivity, image));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share using..."));
}

public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

However, there's one problem: the image stays in the gallery after I don't need it anymore.

Question: Is there a way to share an image from the Internet without saving it first?

Comment: It is just what you call sharing. Isn't sending the url enough?

Comment: @greenapps No, I need to actually share an image. I need to pass it using `.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)` so that it's shared, not just the url. Users don't want to click on a link that takes them to a page with an image. They want to see actually see the image in the post

Comment: Sharing? You want to sent the image. By mail?

Comment: @greenapps By any app that is able to share it. Facebook, Instagram, Pinterest, Gmail, Text message client... etc

Comment: You don't have to save it to the gallery. Just save it to your apps cache dir. There you can later easily delete it.

Comment: @greenapps How can I do that?

Comment: Write your ByteArrayOutputStream bytes to file instead of activating the MediaStore to do that.

Comment: @greenapps Wouldn't that still save the file to SD card?

Comment: You can save it where you want: in external or removable memory. Under kitkat you are restricted to apps private directories when in removable media.

Comment: @greenapps So the answer to my question is "it's impossible"? Is it impossible to share an image without saving it to memory? If so, how can I delete it? I don't want the image to exist in external memory after it's shared.

Comment: You can delete files using File:delete().